# Effect of Voltage sag on IT Equipment

Tags: voltage, computers

Let say I have IT equipment that is rated for 100V to 240V.  I plug it into a 208V receptacle that it unprotected (no UPS or surge suppression).  What would happen if there were a voltage sag on 40%.  the incoming voltage would drip from 208V to 125V.  Would this cause my IT equipment to fail?

Answer (score 3):

> What would happen if there were a voltage sag on 40%. the incoming voltage would drip from 208V to 125V. Would this cause my IT equipment to fail?

No.

The wide input voltage rating means that it is using switched-mode technology. The mains voltage is rectified and then "chopped" or switched at high frequency into a small transformer and stepped down the the required output voltage(s). As mains voltage or load varies the onboard voltage regulator adjusts the switching to maintain the required output.

[image]

*Figure 1. Switched mode power supply block diagram. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply).*

Note that since power = volts x amps (\$ P = VI \$) that for a given output power requirement the input current will increase as the input voltage drops.